# How to rectify connection of MySQL to Excel 2010

Tags: mysql, excel

Hello I have seen questions on these type of problem but I am not able to rectify my problem. Please help it.
I am taking the steps as mentioned in the below link to connect MySQL with Excel 2010.

http://www.enduserguides.com/software/office/mso/eug_mysqlodbc.html

I have created the data source with the help of administrative tool and specified the username and password of my MySQL database in computer.

In the 6th step (in excel file choosing "from data sources"> "from data connection wizard") after specifying the data source name (which I created earlier). When I am clicking on test connection it is showing message "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Unspecified error".

Also if I am specifying the username, password and then clicking on test connection then also same error.

I am not able to find the problem in this I have followed each and every step of that link.

Comment: looks like an error with the ODBC driver.. are u sure you download the correct version of the ODBC driver. And for mysql and excel I use this for connectivity: http://www.mysql.de/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Comment: I have downloaded "mysql connector odbc 5.1.13 winx64" for installing ODBC in my computer having Windows 7. I dont know which version to download can you help me regarding this.

Comment: try from the link I provided to you